# "...use/go to the bathroom"

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Flight attendant: You have to stay in your seat.

Passenger: Oh, **I just have to use the bathroom.**/**I just have to go to the bathroom.**

Flight attendant: You're going to have to wait till we have landed.

Questions:

1. "use", "go to", what is natural here?
2. Would it be more normal to use "toilet" instead of "bathroom" if on a standard plane?

Comment: You may need to specify which dialect of English you are thinking of. In the UK a bathroom is a room with a bath in it so we would naturally prefer toilet here.

Comment: https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/03/toilet.html  Either _use_ or _go to_ is acceptable.

Comment: I once heard an American say (jocularly, I think) 'Do bears use the bathroom in the woods?'

Answer (score 1):

To me, “use the bathroom” is idiomatic to American English, and “go to the toilet” is idiomatic to British English (though it’s also idiomatic and polite to say “use your/the toilet” in British English, for example, when you’re a guest in someone’s home - saying “use” is a way to acknowledge their ownership and what we acknowledge may be seen as our imposition, though there is also a general acknowledgment that it would be impolite of the host to view it that way).

“Bathroom” is much more American, “toilet” is much more British (so much so that in Britain you may hear seemingly bizarre things like, “Can I use your toilet? I just need to wash my hands.”)

Comment: Bathroom and toilet are pretty interchangeable in the U.S. I do hear toilet used more by older people, though. Either can be used to describe the room or place, the apparatus (commode), or the act of relieving ones self (even when not in the location of the actual bathroom/toilet). Restroom is even more common than either of the first to terms. You see it used for signage almost exclusively. So, people tend to use it in speech more. Traveling overseas, especially to non-English Speaking countries, WC (for water closet) seemed very common.

Comment: @Dean F.: Thanks - a valuable addition! - particularly the word “restroom”, which I failed to recall as a very common term for a public bathroom/toilet in America.

Comment: No worries. Restroom is the most common here. The first two terms are used as well. But, they are mixed in with a plethora of other terms (head, john, loo, crapper, throne, porcelain goddess, latrine, can, etc). Which word used can be very dependent on the persons background and upbringing as well as the formality of the situation. Pretty much all are universally understood. We don’t use the terms WC or water closet in the U.S., though

Comment: My father (English, born 1920) used to say 'Do you wish to make use of the lavatory before we leave?'. My mother called it 'the lav'. I do both of these, but I'll say 'toilet' if I am with people who won't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Either term is fine. You may also use the term “I must go use the bathroom.” The word “use” describes more of the act or action itself. Whereas the word “go” describes more of transporting your body to the location of use with the presumption of use.